# Page navi is not working in custom taxonomy template?

Tags: php, wordpress

> I have a custom taxonomy template **`taxonomy-event-category.php`** and i
>   have added following code for pagination but it does not work.

```
<?php
$current_term = single_term_title("", false);
$cat_id = get_cat_ID('My Category');
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'paged'=>$paged,

    'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'event-categories',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $current_term,

        ),
    ),
);
$new = new WP_Query($args);

while( $new->have_posts() ):  $new->the_post();

    /* OUTPUT HERE */
endwhile;

if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) ) {
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $new ) );

}

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

> whenever i click on the next page or second page getting me **`404`**
>   page not found error.
>
> Anyone have idea about how pagnavi work in custom taxonomy template.

Comment: When you click on next page, what URL does it take you to?

Comment: http://servarname/athena/events/categories/athena-meetings/page/2/

Comment: Wordpress returns 404 because it's not aware of the existence of other pages (because in the Wordpress settings you've set to display some other number of posts per page, and here you're using a custom query to display them instead of the default query). I'm not sure why you put a custom query inside the file. If you are in the taxonomy term page then you can rely on the global query (which Wordpress sets automatically with the correct parameters) and just  do something like:
  
`while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ......endwhile; if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }`

Comment: still is not working, in Wordpress  setting  i have set  1.